# DRIVER for DELL nVIDIA LAPTOP

Tags: nvidia, graphics, dell-vostro, gpu-driver

I purchased, DELL Vostro-3558-Latop series with i3 5th Gen, 1TB HDD, 2G nVidia Graphics, 4GB DDR3 RAM and Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. I am totally at mercy of DELL Support. During software update the laptop got hanged and corrupted the installed operating system.

DELL Support raised their hands and said they do not support in UBUNTU.

Now somehow i managed to install the UBUNTU 16.04, but i am not able to see the appropriate driver for nVidia 920m graphics.

Please help me in getting the same restored back the nVidia Settings for enabling/disabling the graphics.

By any way like GUI, command etc.

Comment: 1. If your Dell had factory installed Ubuntu then Dell must support it. 2. You should be able to select and install the recommended Nvidia driver at System Settings > Software Properties > Additional Drivers (tab).

Answer (score 0):

Graphics card drivers are not generally available by `sudo apt-get update`. You should go to

> system settings -> software & updates

[image: Software Updates]

and click on the `Additional Driver` tab. There you should see proprietary drivers available for use.

[image: Proprietary Softwares]

In your case details of software should indicate that the driver is for Graphics Card. You should tick the radio button which will enable the use of the driver. Then apply changes.
I hope it resolves your issue.